# How long can I access a friend's list offline after that person connects via facebook connect?

Tags: facebook

I want be able to send a list of friends & recent additions from someones facebook account to an email address daily or weekly.

Looking up online, I think the best approach would be to setup a website, where a user would facebook connect with their facebook credentials & accept all terms including accessing their friends list.  The website would then run a batch job nightly to access that persons friend list, do a matchup and then send an e-mail with the summary of their findings.

Is this possible?  Can I just do a onetime login and get forever access to someones friend list, assuming they do not manually revoke access to the application within fb?  looking for suggestions.  I know there is way to access a profile offline, but how long is that session available for?  I know the policy has changed, AND can change in the future by trying to understand the current state of accessing a friends list offline.

Also, am I violating any policies by doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask the user for an offline_access permission and read_friendlists permission, that way you'll get an accessToken that does not expire.

More info here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

as long as you don't save data you'll be fine

Comment: Had a question regarding a section from the link you posted.  It mentions by "default" most access tokens expire after a short time period.  Does that mean I can change how long that access is?  I don't see anywhere where it says the accesstoken does not expire.

Comment: From the link:   offline_access - Enables your application to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.